# Twilio conference voicemail/machine detection

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I am building an application in which we add 20 people to a conference for an important discussion,
and suppose one or two of participants (From the 20 people added to the conference) is not available and their voicemail is active,
then in the middle of an important discussion those prerecorded voicemail messages/audio starts, this is very annoying for others in the conference. 
I want to prevent this from happening.

> I have tried using ifMachine but it did not help, MachineDetection
>   callback URL is not is also not getting called, same is the case for AnsweredBy as well.

I am following [MachineDetection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#rich-text).

My code is as follows

```
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const client = new Twilio(account_sid, authToken);

mobileArr.forEach(function(number,ind) {
        console.log("mobile array iteration",ind, number,'    '+twilioCallBackUrl+'twilioMachineWebhook');
        client
          .conferences(conferences.title)
          .participants.create({
            machineDetection: 'Enable',
            url:twilioMachinecallback,
            to: number,
            from: user.twilioDetails.number,
            statusCallback: twilioCallWebhook,
            statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
            statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
            Timeout: '15',
            method: 'GET',
        }, function(err, participant) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('conf failed because: '+ err + '   ' + helper.authToken + '   ' +client.accountSid);
            } else {

            }
        })
    })
```

I am new to Twilio please suggest and help if have I done anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [participants resource does not list the `machineDetection` or `Url` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#code-retrieve-all-participants) as available parameters when creating a call directly into a conference. This is because this API call dials a participant directly into the conference call.

To handle the machine detection you will need to make the call using the regular [Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call). In this API request you can set `machineDetection` to `Enable` and set a `Url`. You'll need your URL to be able to handle the `AnsweredBy` parameter and either, if it is `human`, return the TwiML to dial your user into the [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference) or just [`<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup) on the machine.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: according to this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#rich-text) machineDetection is enabled only in selected countries.
Also according to above [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#block-markdown) the machineDetection takes in parameter
Enable, but i will go for true as you have mentioned.

Comment: can you give me an idea or reference with which I can use [Call Screening](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/ivr-screening-node-express) with the above conference creation code.

Comment: You're right, `machineDetection` takes `Enable` as the arguement, my mistake. The important part is that creating a conference participant doesn't support `machineDetection` but creating a call that leads to the conference does.

Comment: As for call screening, if you create the call as I've suggested you can use any TwiML to direct the call before it gets to the conference. So, rather than straight `<Dial>`ing into the `<Conference>` you could `<Say>` a message and get the user to enter a pin number or just respond with the keypad and use `<Gather>` to get that response and conditionally direct them into the `<Conference>`.

Comment: So basically,
1. I have to create a call
2. Then I have to use gather 
3. Then add all  these calls to a particular conference 
Is this process right?
Can you give a reference or example of the process please.

Comment: That is correct. Here's a [tutorial on getting user input with `<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-node-js) and this is [how to create conference calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls-node-js). I don't have a complete example of what you want to do, you will need to combine what you have already with these tutorials and the other links I've given in this answer.

Comment: Not with dialling a participant directly into a conference, but it can be used when you make a regular call from the REST API using the calls resource as I linked in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that AMD machine Detection is not a reliable option.

> Hence I went for [alternatives-to-amd](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132567-Can-Twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine-#alternatives-to-amd) which is also known as [Call
>   Screening](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/ivr-screening-node-express).

It's reliable. The steps are as follows:

> 1. You have to create all calls to be added to the conference.

```
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const client = new Twilio(account_sid, authToken);

mobileArr.forEach(function(number,ind) {
    client.calls
        .create({
            url: 'CallScreening call url',
            from: user.twilioDetails.number,
            to: number,
            statusCallback: 'Your call status callback url',
            statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
            statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
            Timeout: '15',
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .then(call => {
            console.log(call)
    })
});
```

> 2. Then you have to use gather in **url: 'CallScreening call url'**

```
    const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

    exports.callScreeningWebhook = (req, res) => {
        console.log('callScreeningWebhook');
        console.log(req.body);
        const twiml = new VoiceResponse();


        const gather = twiml.gather({
            input:'dtmf',
            timeout: 20,
            numDigits: 1,
            action: twilioCallBackUrl+'gatherAction'
        });
        gather.say('Please enter any digits to join conference');

        // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());
    }
```

> 3. Then add all these calls to a particular conference using the [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) method callback.

```
exports.gatherAction = (req, res) => {
    console.log('gatherAction');

    console.log(req.body);
    const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

    if (req.body.Digits) {

        var input = parseInt(req.body.Digits)
        console.log('HEllo',typeof input);
        if (!isNaN(input)){
            console.log('JoIN conference data');
            twiml.say('You are being merged to conference');
            const dial = twiml.dial();

            dial.conference({
                statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
                statusCallbackEvent: 'start end join leave',
                statusCallback: twilioCallBackUrl+'twilioConferenceWebhook'
                }, conference.title);
                console.log(twiml.toString());
                console.log('JoIN  Complete')

            res.type('text/xml');
            res.send(twiml.toString());
        }else{
            console.log('input parsing error');
            twiml.say('Invalid input, Please try again')
            twiml.redirect(twilioCallBackUrl+'callScreeningWebhook');
            res.type('text/xml');
            res.send(twiml.toString());
        }
    }else{
        console.log('no input');
        twiml.say('No input, Please try again')
        twiml.pause({length: 10});
        twiml.redirect(twilioCallBackUrl+'gatherFailure');
        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());
    }
```

}

The code for **gatherFailure** is as follows

```
    exports.gatherFailure = (req, res) => {

        console.log('gatherFailure');
        console.log(req.body);
        const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
        twiml.hangup();
        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());

}
```

In this way by using gather anyone call detect whether call was answered by a human or not and perform any suitable action required.

Once again a big thank's to **philnash**.