# Async AMD for conferences

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I need to perform AMD on a conference participant. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271503/twilio-conference-voicemail-machine-detection) that I would not be able to do this using the participant resource, and needed to leverage the call resource instead, along with twiml to connect to the conference.

I was able to do this. but had to remove the functionality as the conference behavior became sporadic, and unexpected. We only ever expect 2 participants, but would receive 3 participant join events. What might cause an issue like this? The ID used for the conference is unique to the participants, they may attempt to join the conference more than once with the same ID.

To connect the first participant, the following twiml is used:

```
<Response>
  <Play>...</Play>
  <Dial>
    <Conference
     startConferenceOnEnter="false"
     endConferenceOnExit="true"
     statusCallback="..."
     statusCallbackEvent="start end join leave"
     record="record-from-start"
     >
     #{id}
    </Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

To connect the second:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference
     startConferenceOnEnter="true"
     endConferenceOnExit="true"
     >
     #{id}
    </Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>

# With Call parameters
# machine_detection: "Enable",
# async_amd: true
# async_amd_status_callback: ...
```